# Trying to run a curl command through Java - How to tag a file as an input through the command

Tags: java, curl

I am trying to run a curl command while sending a file as an input to the url

For example

I have a curl command :

```
`curl -s -X POST "dummy/url"

-H Content-Type:text/xml

 --data-binary @dummy.xml`
```

How do I run this command through Java and sent the file as an input to the command

Comment: Are you wanting to output something from java to send it?

Or are you  wanting to call curl from in Java? Java can also call URLs and post data, so that makes little sense to start and external process for this.

Comment: Our attempt to run the URL was unsuccessful as it necessitates a file to operate. Our objective is to exclusively execute the curl command using Java.